# Elastic JS node JS unable to update index

Tags: node.js, express, elasticjs

I Have this strange error while I'm trying to update an index on elasticJS using express:

```
router.put('/update/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('Entered updateuser', req.params.id);
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    let password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    const data = {
      email: req.body.email,
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      password
    };

    await client.update({
      index: 'users',
      type: 'mytype',
      id: req.params.id,
      body: data
    });
    res.json({ msg: 'Updated Successfully' });
  } catch (err) {
    // res.status(500).send(err.message);
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

I've checked all the parameters are there but I get an error :

```
use the endpoint /{index}/_update/{id} instead."' ],

[0]      meta:
[0]       { context: null,
[0]         request: [Object],
[0]         name: 'elasticsearch-js',
[0]         connection: [Object],
[0]         attempts: 0,
[0]         aborted: false } } }
[0] Entered updateuser GIt7NW0BKLEzmnN0prT2
[0] { ResponseError: x_content_parse_exception
[0]         request: [Object],
[0]         name: 'elasticsearch-js',
[0]         connection: [Object],
[0]         attempts: 0,
[0]         aborted: false } } }
```

does anyone know whats the problem?

Comment: the request body sent to elastic is wrong. That means some variable in `data` variable either is missing or is not sent correctly

Comment: @NikosM. well I checked all the fields and nothing is missing..

Comment: maybe they are in the wrong format

Comment: @NikosM. they are all strings, I don't think it is, maybe i'm missing some parameter?

Comment: this is the error `ResponseError: x_content_parse_exception`, a quick lookup yields: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problems-with-role-based-access-x-content-parse-exception/148796, https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30261

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `update` api and update part of a document you have to wrap your changes in `doc`.

```
await client.update({
  index: 'users',
  type: 'mytype',
  id: req.params.id,
  body: { 
     doc: data // <===
  }
});
```

[Update part of a document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/docs-update.html#_update_part_of_a_document)